# dynamically populating data in charsequence

Tags: java, android, charsequence

I have a charsequence in which I want to populate data dynamically. when I am hard coding the values its working fine, otherwise not

**This one is working**

```
private void getDir(String dirPath){

     File f = new File(dirPath);
     File[] files = f.listFiles(); 
         final CharSequence[] items = {files[0].getPath(), files[1].getPath()};
}
```

**This one is giving a runtime exception**

```
private void getDir(String dirPath){

     File f = new File(dirPath);
     File[] files = f.listFiles(); 
         CharSequence[] items;
         items[0]=files[0].getPath();
     items[1]=files[1].getPath();
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the items array and specify its size.

Try something like:

```
private void getDir(String dirPath){

    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[files.length];
    for (int i=0; i< files.length; i++)
        items[i]=files[i].getPath();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize  `CharSequence[] items;` in your 2nd implementation.

You could try `CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[2];`

Comment: its correct but I want a very dynamic code.@don's implementation is perfect for my situation. Thanks for your help :)